# Get the content of radio buttons in an array

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following list of radio buttons from this [website](https://www.ifrs.org/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/):

```
<div class="map-filters">
        <div class="map-filter-radio radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="adoptionStatus" alt="IFRS Standards are required for use by all or most domestic publicly accountable entities." title="IFRS Standards are required for use by all or most domestic publicly accountable entities." value="97f9b22998d546f7856bb1b4f0586521">
                IFRS Standards are required for domestic public companies
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="map-filter-radio radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="adoptionStatus" alt="IFRS Standards are permitted, but not required, for use by at least some domestic publicly accountable entities, including listed companies and financial institutions." title="IFRS Standards are permitted, but not required, for use by at least some domestic publicly accountable entities, including listed companies and financial institutions." value="cae64c6b731d47cca7565b2a74d11d53">
                IFRS Standards are permitted but not required for domestic public companies
            </label>
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the text in the label tag and the value of the input type radio like below :

```
Key                              Value
97f9b22998d546f7856bb1b4f0586521 IFRS Standards are required for domestic public companies
cae64c6b731d47cca7565b2a74d11d53 IFRS Standards are permitted but not required for domestic public companies
```

This is my work :

```
session = HTMLSession()
resp = session.get("https://www.ifrs.org/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/")
resp.html.render()
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.html.html, "lxml")
option_tags = soup.find("input",{"name":"adoptionStatus"})
filters = [tag.text for tag in option_tags]
print(filters)
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with the retrieved text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `key` by accessing the `value` HTML attribute. And access `value` by using the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
resp = session.get(
    "https://www.ifrs.org/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/"
)
resp.html.render()
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.html.html, "lxml")

fmt_string = "{:<40} {:<20}"
print(fmt_string.format("Key", "Value"))

for tag in soup.find_all("input", {"name": "adoptionStatus"}):
    print(fmt_string.format(tag["value"], tag.next_sibling.strip()))
```

Output:

```
Key                                      Value               
97f9b22998d546f7856bb1b4f0586521         IFRS Standards are required for domestic public companies
cae64c6b731d47cca7565b2a74d11d53         IFRS Standards are permitted but not required for domestic public companies
3adc18f07ff64c908a6d835e08344531         IFRS Standards are required or permitted for listings by foreign companies
665a976cd22f4b2db99c57e2ab98e633         The IFRS for SMEs Standard is required or permitted
ff784361818644798ea899f81b8b6d61         The IFRS for SMEs Standard is under consideration
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ifrs.org/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/"
page_html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "lxml").find_all("input", {"type": "radio"})
buttons = [[button["alt"], button["value"]] for button in soup]

for button in buttons:
    text, value = button
    print(f"Text: {text}\nValue: {value}")
```

Output:

```
Text: IFRS Standards are required for use by all or most domestic publicly accountable entities.
Value: 97f9b22998d546f7856bb1b4f0586521
Text: IFRS Standards are permitted, but not required, for use by at least some domestic publicly accountable entities, including listed companies and financial institutions.
Value: cae64c6b731d47cca7565b2a74d11d53
Text: IFRS Standards are required or permitted for use by foreign securities issuers.
Value: 3adc18f07ff64c908a6d835e08344531
Text: In most cases an SME may also choose full IFRS Standards. In some cases, an SME may also choose local standards for SMEs.
Value: 665a976cd22f4b2db99c57e2ab98e633
Text: The body with authority to adopt financial reporting standards is actively studying whether to adopt the <em>IFRS for SMEs</em> Standard.
Value: ff784361818644798ea899f81b8b6d61
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value_tags = soup.find("div", class_="map-filter-radio radio").text.strip()
key_tag = option_tags.attrs["value"]
```

this is for first element

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't matter to have the full text version, rather than the shorter, you can use a faster match with css and a class selector

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(requests.get('https://www.ifrs.org/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/').text, 'lxml')
items = {i['id']:i.text for i in soup.select('.status-text')}
print(items)
```